# How do I display custom tooltips in a CTreeCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip, mfc-feature-pack

I have a class derived from `CTreeCtrl`. In `OnCreate()` I replace the default `CToolTipCtrl` object with a custom one:

```
int CMyTreeCtrl::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CTreeCtrl::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // Replace tool tip with our own which will
    // ask us for the text to display with a TTN_NEEDTEXT message
    CTooltipManager::CreateToolTip(m_pToolTip, this, AFX_TOOLTIP_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    m_pToolTip->AddTool(this, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK);
    SetToolTips(m_pToolTip);

    // Update: Added these two lines, which don't help either
    m_pToolTip->Activate(TRUE);
    EnableToolTips(TRUE);
    
    return 0;
}
```

My message handler looks like this:

```
ON_NOTIFY_EX(TTN_NEEDTEXT, 0, &CMyTreeCtrl::OnTtnNeedText)
```

However I never receive a `TTN_NEEDTEXT` message. I had a look with Spy++ and it also looks like this message never gets sent.

What could be the problem here?

### Update

I'm not sure whether this is relevant: The `CTreeCtrl`'s parent window is of type `CDockablePane`. Could there be some extra work needed for this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally! I (partially) solved it:

It looks like the CDockablePane parent window indeed caused this problem...

First I removed all the tooltip-specific code from the CTreeCtrl-derived class. Everything is done in the parent pane window.

Then I edited the parent window's `OnCreate()` method:

```
int CMyPane::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

const DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
    TVS_CHECKBOXES | TVS_DISABLEDRAGDROP | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT |
    TVS_INFOTIP | TVS_NOHSCROLL | TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS;

// TREECTRL_ID is a custom member constant, set to 1
if(!m_tree.Create(dwStyle, m_treeRect, this, TREECTRL_ID ) )
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create trace tree list control.\n");
    return -1;
}

// m_pToolTip is a protected member of CDockablePane
m_pToolTip->AddTool(&m_tree, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK, &m_treeRect, TREECTRL_ID);
m_tree.SetToolTips(m_pToolTip);


return 0;
```

}

Unforunately we cannot simply call `AddTool()` with less parameters because the base class will complain in the form of an `ASSERT` about a `uFlag` member if there is no tool ID set.
And since we need to set the ID, we also need to set a rectangle. I created a `CRect` member and set it to `(0, 0, 10000, 10000)` in the CTor. I have not yet found a working way to change the tool's rect size so this is my very ugly workaround. This is also why I call this solution partial. **Update: [I asked a question regarding this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867724/how-to-modify-the-tool-rect-of-a-ctooltipctrl)**

Finally there is the handler to get the tooltip info:

```
// Message map entry
ON_NOTIFY(TVN_GETINFOTIP, TREECTRL_ID, &CMobileCatalogPane::OnTvnGetInfoTip)


// Handler
void CMyPane::OnTvnGetInfoTip(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMTVGETINFOTIP pGetInfoTip = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTVGETINFOTIP>(pNMHDR);

    // This is a CString member
    m_toolTipText.ReleaseBuffer();
    m_toolTipText.Empty();

    // Set your text here...

    pGetInfoTip->pszText = m_toolTipText.GetBuffer();

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you still have to enable the tooltip, even though you are replacing the builtin.

```
EnableToolTips(TRUE);
```

Well, since that did not work for you and since no-one more expert has offered any help, here a few more suggestions from me.  Although they are lame, they might get you moving again:

- Make sure your OnCreate() rotine is actually being executed.
- Enable the tool tip BEFORE you replace it.
- The code I use to do this looks like this. ( I confess I do not understand all the details, I copied it from some sample code, it worked and so I never looked at it any more. )

  // Enable the standard tooltip

  EnableToolTips(TRUE);

  // Disable the builtin tooltip

  CToolTipCtrl* pToolTipCtrl = (CToolTipCtrl*)CWnd::FromHandle((HWND)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, LVM_GETTOOLTIPS, 0, 0L));

Comment: This does not seem to have any effect. I added it to the code  though. Along with a call to CToolTipCtrl::Activate().

Comment: Thanks for the update! Unfortunately I don't get any further here...
I verified that OnCreate() gets called and enabling tool tips _before_ replacing seems to have no effect.
Neither has the SendMessage() call. I believe this only retrieves a pointer and does not actually disable anything.

Comment: Well, that's a shame.  It's odd that no-one has contributed.  I can only suggest that you build the simplest possible application to display a tooltip on a test tree, and see if that works.

BTW, the Sendmessage() does more than retrieve a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried in a CTreeCtrl but I think you should call RelayEvent for the tooltip ctrl to know when the tooltip has to be displayed. Try this:

MyTreeCtrl.h:

```
virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg);
```

MyTreeCtrl.cpp:

```
BOOL CMyTreeCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
    m_pToolTip.Activate(TRUE);
    m_pToolTip.RelayEvent(pMsg);

    return CTreeCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

I hope this help.

Comment: In a forum I read, that one has to call RelayEvent() if the control belongs to a dialog. However the example didn't mention to call Activate(). I tried your suggestion, but still no success...

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. As I told you I haven't tried neither with a CTreeCtrl nor in a CDockablePane. Maybe if you can upload the application, we could have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to override OnToolHitTest()?

[(old) Resource 1](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=557485)

[(old) Resource 2:](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0397/c/c0397.aspx)

> In addition to returning the hit code (nHit), you also have to fill out the TOOLINFO struct. Here's how VIRGIL does it in CMainFrame::OnToolHitTest:

```
 int nHit = MAKELONG(pt.x, pt.y);
 pTI->hwnd = m _ hWnd;
 pTI->uId  = nHit;
 pTI->rect = CRect(CPoint(pt.x-1,pt.y-1),CSize(2,2));
 pTI->uFlags |= TTF _ NOTBUTTON;
 pTI->lpszText = LPSTR _ TEXTCALLBACK;
```

Most of this is obvious—like setting hwnd and uId—but some of it is less so. I set the rect member to a 2-pixel-wide, 2-pixel-high rectangle centered around the mouse location. The tooltip control uses this rectangle as the bounding rectangle of the "tool," which I want to be tiny, so moving the mouse anywhere will constitute moving outside the tool. I set TTF _ NOTBUTTON in uFlags because the tooltip is not associated with a button. This is a special MFC flag defined in afxwin.h; MFC uses it to do help for tooltips. There's another MFC-extended flag for tooltips, TTF _ ALWAYSTIP. You can use it if you want MFC to display the tip even when your window is not active.
You may have noticed that so far I haven't told MFC or the tooltip or the TOOLINFO what the actual text of the tip is. That's what LPSTR _ TEXTCALLBACK is for. This special value tells the tooltip control (the internal, thread-global one that MFC uses) to call my window back to get the text. It does this by sending my window a WM _ NOTIFY message with notification code TTN _ NEEDTEXT.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I still don't receive the TTN_NEEDTEXT notification...

Answer (score 0):

Try to specifically handle all tooltip ids:

```
ON_NOTIFY_EX_RANGE(TTN_NEEDTEXT, 0, 0xFFFF, &CMyTreeCtrl::OnNeedTipText)
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to manually call RelayEvent() from PreTranslateMessage().