# How to modify the tool rect of a CToolTipCtrl?

Tags: c++, tooltip, mfc-feature-pack

This question is [related to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269837/how-do-i-display-custom-tooltips-in-a-ctreectrl).

In a CDockablePane derived class I have a CTreeCtrl member for which I add a ToolTip in OnCreate():

```
int CMyPane::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    const DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
        TVS_CHECKBOXES | TVS_DISABLEDRAGDROP | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT |
        TVS_INFOTIP | TVS_NOHSCROLL | TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS;

    if(!m_tree.Create(dwStyle, m_treeRect, this, TREECTRL_ID) ) { return -1; }

    m_pToolTip->AddTool(&m_tree, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK, &m_treeRect, TREECTRL_ID);
    m_tree.SetToolTips(m_pToolTip);


    return 0;
}
```

I have to call AddTool() with all of the optional parameters because the default values won't work with CDockablePane.
`m_treeRect` is a `CRect` member set to `(0, 0, 10000, 10000)` in the CTor. This is really ugly.

I would like to adjust the tool's rectangle whenever `m_tree`'s size changes.
So I tried some stuff in `CMyPane::OnSize()` but none of it worked:

- Calling `m_pToolTip->GetToolInfo()` then modify the `CToolInfo`'s rect member, then calling `SetToolInfo()`
- Calling `m_pToolTip->SetToolRect()`

How is it meant to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know no other way to do this other than calling `DelTool` then `AddTool` again in your `OnSize` handler:

```
void CMyPane::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDockablePane::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if (m_pToolTip != NULL)
    {
        m_pToolTip->DelTool(&m_tree, TREECTRL_ID);

        CRect treeRect;
        m_tree.GetClientRect(treeRect);

        m_pToolTip->AddTool(&m_tree, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK, &treeRect, TREECTRL_ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int CMyPane::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    const DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
        TVS_CHECKBOXES | TVS_DISABLEDRAGDROP | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT |
        TVS_INFOTIP | TVS_NOHSCROLL | TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS;

    if(!m_tree.Create(dwStyle, m_treeRect, this, TREECTRL_ID) ) { return -1; }

    m_pToolTip->AddTool(&m_tree, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK, &m_treeRect, TREECTRL_ID);
    m_tree.SetToolTips(m_pToolTip);


    return 0;
}
```